# Getting an error IE9 SCRIPT5009 'jQuery' not defined for a select few computer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP web application, a client called me today stating that the search was not working, everything works great here and at our other clients, I went through it with them and the browser mode and document mode are both set to IE9 and checked the active scripting was enabled. I am wondering if anyone has encountered this before. Any help would be wonderful as I cannot debug the problem as I do not get the error.

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is without the code so need to rule things out. Have you got any iframes on the page?

Comment: Are you using the CDN to load jQuery? If so, it may be blocked on the client's computer.

Comment: You say "for a select few computers" but your question only mentions one client. It's really important to be as accurate as possible. Did you mean that this was tried on other computers at the same location and also failed?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will answer your questions, not using iframes, and I am referring to one client as I was working with one person in the group, and Jay you have the solution, I never would have thought of that. I downloaded a copy of jquery and now that group is no longer getting the error.

Comment: It could be a mismatch between the HTTP protocols on the page and the source URL for jQuery, for instance if the page is loaded via HTTPS but the jQuery script specifies HTTP in the SCRIPT tag.